# What do you call a course at university that is not part of a programme?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

As the heading says: what do you call a course at uni that's not part of a programme? My bilingual dictionary suggests *freestanding course*, but to my ears, that sounds extremely odd. Or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on the university really, and the country / education system it operates in. At my (UK) university we had *core* modules which everyone on the course had to take, there were *options* which were part of the course but you could choose which ones you took, and we had *electives* which could be anything you wanted from any part of the university, but which didn't count towards your course.

Some universities allow for *minors / academic minors* which are a side degree with lower requirements, which people study alongside their *major* (the main course they're taking). There can be lots of reasons to do this (often just to gain an education in something important or interesting, or to make their degree more attractive to employers) but as far as I'm aware the details and requirements vary from place to place. We didn't have that concept in the UK when I was at university (not that I'm aware of anyway!)

Since there's no simple, widely used term for it, I think it would be better to use a general description like *optional course* or *side course* that makes it clear to the reader that it's not an integral part of the main programme. *Freestanding* **might** be understood, but it's also not clear exactly what it means. But if you're referring to something specific (a course offered while on a programme at a specific institution) and they have a name for it, it might be best to just use that.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think you're right that it depends on the education system. In my country we have these courses that you can either study in their own right, without getting a degree, or that you can piece together to end up being the equivalent of a programme (for which you receive a degree), without your having actually studied in the programme. So... I guess the best way to deal with this would be to use the expression suggested in my dictionary, but use citation marks, and then just add an explanatory footnote. Thanks again!!

Comment: Ohhh I think I know the kind of thing you're talking about, where you earn some kind of credit towards a qualification? Yeah, that would be a very specific thing, and I'd use the official name for whatever that is! But most people probably wouldn't know what that **is** anyway, so it depends whether you need to just use the right term, or if you need to really explain what the course is by using a descriptive name.

Comment: That's exactly it, yes :)

Comment: Hey cactustictacs – what do you think about simply using "independent course"? That should work, shouldn't it? As long as it's not already used specifically for a particular kind of course?

Comment: Honestly I don't know - it sounds like you're writing material for a prospectus or generally describing what an institution offers, right? I feel like that's going to require some "industry lingo", and I don't really have any knowledge of that. But to my ear, reading some university literature (or whatever) and seeing *independent course* makes it sound like the course is *independent* of the university, like some kind of outside provision by another institution or something. I know you said on another answer that you can't call everything a *programme*, but that's the most general to me

Comment: Ah, right... that would be an unfortunate interpretation... Haha, yeah – no, I'm translating a document for my faculty, so I have to come up with English equivalents to a lot of culture-specific stuff... which is not an easy task! So yeah, you're absolutely right there is already highly specific "industry lingo" in place; it's just that it's not in English... Oh well; I'm truly and deeply grateful to you (and others) for all your help anyway <3

Comment: Ohhh I thought you were at a university in an English-speaking country, composing original writing in English. If it's a translation then I suppose you have more freedom! Maybe look at some other material your faculty or school has produced in the past, and use their terms for consistency. Otherwise *course* and *programme* might be interchangeable - you can have a *course of study* and a *programme of study*. And *programme* is a general word for "a plan or schedule of events, activities, things to achieve etc." so honestly that would probably work for any kind of course or whatever

Comment: Also maybe you meant *individual course* instead of *independent*? That has more of a sense of treating each one separately, without making that separateness a feature of what it *is*. If you have a group of people they're all *individual*, but *independent* implies a lack of connection to each other. I think *individual courses* might fit better with what you're going for!